# How to copy a value in new dataframe based on key links of another dataframe like ID, start and end value? (in R)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two datasets of trip durations and parking durations, and I want to put distance travelled of trips in parking durations in the way which every distance travelled would go to in rows of parking durations that is going to happen after trip as shown in picture. I would like to this task do in R, but I am lacking some skills to make that happen. Any suggestions? Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Hi Asrorkhuja Ortikov. It's not toally clear what you want to do. If you want to improve your question, here is some information on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [minimale reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). The MRE will make it easier for others to find and test a answer to your question. That way you can help others to help you!

Comment: I think what they want to do is match trip end with parking start. I.e. they park after they have finished their trip and they want to see the distance they traveled before parking.

Comment: @dario I have edited my question, hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: @JordanHackett exactly

Comment: @AsrorkhujaOrtikov please check the links provided,  which would have mentioned the edit should have contained parts of the data. Just changing wording is not enough to make a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Annet, now I understood. Will improve next time for sure, so far code is working perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are phrasing your question at this moment it looks like you want a simple join. Using the `tidyverse` package:

```
library(tidyverse)
trip <- tibble(ID= c("car1","car1","car2","car2"), 
               start_trip = c("6:30","16:15", "07:05","15:30"), 
               end_trip = c("7:00","16:45","07:40","16:05"), 
               trip_distance = c(20,30,25,20))

parking <- tibble(ID= c("car1","car1","car1","car2","car2","car2"), 
               end = c("6:30","16:15","0:00", "07:05","15:30","0:00"), 
               start = c("0:00","7:00","16:45","0:00","07:40","16:05"))

parking %>% left_join(trip %>% select(-start_trip), by = c("start" = "end_trip", "ID"))
```

which will result in

```
ID    end   start trip_distance
  <chr> <chr> <chr>         <dbl>
1 car1  6:30  0:00             NA
2 car1  16:15 7:00             20
3 car1  0:00  16:45            30
4 car2  07:05 0:00             NA
5 car2  15:30 07:40            25
6 car2  0:00  16:05            20
```

So I match the times from the trip dataframe to the times of the parking dataframe (assuming the end of a trip results in exactly the same parking time!). Also, the Car ID has to match. IF there is no match the distance will be NA. I removed the start_trip from the trip dataframe as you did not give that one in your example.